# GCC ver 7.3.0 preprocessor fails if output file doesn't exist

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I tried to build the [FreeIPMI](https://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/) on a box with GCC 7.3.0 and got stuck - the preprocessor complained that output file was missing:

```
nekto@ubuntu:~/freeipmi-1.6.1/man$ /usr/bin/cpp -nostdinc -w -C -P -I../man libipmiconsole.3.pre libipmiconsole.3
cpp: error: libipmiconsole.3: No such file or directory
```

That's output file, its existence shouldn't be checked I think.

BTW, the same command worked flawlessly on another box with GCC 6.

Is it issue with the GCC 7.3.0 preprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

The invocation format for the GCC 7.3.0 preprocessor has been changed - the output filename has to be prepended by the `-o` option, and all the free-standing filenames on the command line are considered *input* files.

Also the preprocessor became more strict about input formats it supports, so it can't be used to generate man-pages for the FreeIPMI anymore.